# Highlight panda df errors based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, highlight

Good day SO community,

I have been having an issue with trying to highlight errors in my df, row by row.

```
reference_dict = {'jobclass' : ['A','B'], 'Jobs' : ['Teacher','Plumber']}
dict = {'jobclass': ['A','C','A'], 'Jobs': ['Teacher', 'Plumber','Policeman']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict) 

def highlight_rows(df):
  for i in df.index:
    if df.jobclass[i] in reference_dict['jobclass']:
      print(df.jobclass[i])
      return 'background-color: green'

df.style.apply(highlight_rows, axis = 1)
```

I am getting the error:
TypeError: ('string indices must be integers', 'occurred at index 0')

What i hope to get is my df with values not found in my reference_dict being highlighted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Cheers!

Edit:

```
x = {'jobclass' : ['A','B'], 'Jobs' : ['Teacher','Plumber']}
d = {'jobclass': ['A','C','A'], 'Jobs': ['Teacher', 'Plumber','Policeman']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
print(df)
def highlight_rows(s):
  ret = ["" for i in s.index]
  for i in df.index:
    if df.jobclass[i] not in x['jobclass']:
      ret[s.index.get_loc('Jobs')] = "background-color: yellow"
      return ret
df.style.apply(highlight_rows, axis = 1)
```

Tried this and got the whole column highlighted instead of the specific rows values that i desire.. =/

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with parameter `indicator` for found not matched values and then create `DataFrame` of styles:

```
x = {'jobclass' : ['A','B'], 'Jobs' : ['Teacher','Plumber']}
d = {'jobclass': ['A','C','A'], 'Jobs': ['Teacher', 'Plumber','Policeman']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
print (df)
  jobclass       Jobs
0        A    Teacher
1        C    Plumber
2        A  Policeman
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.merge(pd.DataFrame(x) , on='jobclass', how='left', indicator=True))
  jobclass     Jobs_x   Jobs_y     _merge
0        A    Teacher  Teacher       both
1        C    Plumber      NaN  left_only
2        A  Policeman  Teacher       both
```

---

```
def highlight_rows(s):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    c2 = '' 

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(x)
    m = s.merge(df1, on='jobclass', how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'] == 'left_only'
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(c2, index=s.index, columns=s.columns)
    df2.loc[m, 'Jobs'] = c1
    return df2

df.style.apply(highlight_rows, axis = None)
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Hi jezrael, thank you! my solution based on yours has been accepted.

Comment: @hakkonen - You are welcome! Be free upvote my solution too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Good day to you as well!

```
What i hope to get is my df with values not found in my reference_dict being highlighted.
```

If you're looking for values *not* found in reference_dict to be highlighted, do you mean for the function to be the following?

```
def highlight_rows(df):
  for i in df.index:
    if df.jobclass[i] not in reference_dict['jobclass']:
      print(df.jobclass[i])
      return 'background-color: green'
```

Either way, why highlight the rows when you could isolate them? It seems like you want to look at all of the job classes in *df* where there is not one in *reference_dict*.

```
import pandas as pd


reference_dict = {'jobclass' : ['A','B'], 'Jobs' : ['Teacher','Plumber']}

data_dict = {'jobclass': ['A','C','A'], 'Jobs': ['Teacher', 'Plumber','Policeman']}



ref_df = pd.DataFrame(reference_dict)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

outliers = df.merge(ref_df, how='outer', on='jobclass') # merge the two tables together, how='outer' includes jobclasses which the DataFrames do not have in common. Will automatically generate columns Jobs_x and Jobs_y once joined together because the columns have the same name
outliers = outliers[ outliers['Jobs_y'].isnull() ] # Jobs_y is null when there is no matching jobclass in the reference DataFrame, so we can take advantage of that by filtering
outliers = outliers.drop('Jobs_y', axis=1) # let's drop the junk column after we used it to filter for what we wanted

print("The reference DataFrame is:")
print(ref_df,'\n')

print("The input DataFrame is:")
print(df,'\n')

print("The result is a list of all the jobclasses not in the reference DataFrame and what job is with it:")
print(outliers)
```

The result is:

```
The reference DataFrame is:
  jobclass     Jobs
0        A  Teacher
1        B  Plumber 

The input DataFrame is:
  jobclass       Jobs
0        A    Teacher
1        C    Plumber
2        A  Policeman 

The result is a list of all the jobclasses not in the reference DataFrame and what job is with it:
  jobclass   Jobs_x
2        C  Plumber
```

This could have been a tangent but it's what I'd do. I was not aware you could highlight rows in pandas at all, cool trick.

Comment: Thanks Jess, It is useful but i was tasked to make a function that highlights the values tho . But many thanks for your answer!=))

Comment: Ah, okay! Glad you found it useful, hope you figured out the highlighting.